# Java Producer Consumer IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, producer-consumer

I have built producer-consumer using java threads. Producer and consumer are two different class which refers to single LinkedList and object lock. What is the problem with the below implementation?

```
Item Produced by Thread-0 Item 1
Item Consumed by Thread-1 Item 1

    Exception in thread "Thread-0" Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
        at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
        at ProducerConsumer$Producer.produce(ProducerConsumer.java:35)
        at ProducerConsumer$Producer.run(ProducerConsumer.java:19)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
        at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
        at ProducerConsumer$Consumer.consume(ProducerConsumer.java:63)
        at ProducerConsumer$Consumer.run(ProducerConsumer.java:50)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Code implementation

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class ProducerConsumer {
    LinkedList<Integer> items =  new LinkedList<>();
    Object lock = new Object();
    int capacity = 10;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProducerConsumer m = new ProducerConsumer();
        Thread p = new Thread(m.new Producer());
        Thread c =  new Thread(m.new Consumer());
        p.start();
        c.start();
    }

    class Producer implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            produce();
        }

        public void produce(){
            int value =0;
            while(true){
                synchronized (lock){
                    while(items.size() == capacity){
                        try{
                            wait();
                        }catch (InterruptedException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    items.add(++value);
                    System.out.println("Item Produced by "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Item "+value);
                    notify();
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }catch (InterruptedException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Consumer implements Runnable{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            consume();
        }
        public void consume(){
            while (true){
                synchronized (lock){
                    while (items.size() == 0){
                        try{
                            wait();
                        }catch (InterruptedException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("Item Consumed by "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Item "+items.remove());
                    notify();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
        at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
        at ProducerConsumer$Producer.produce(ProducerConsumer.java:35)
        at ProducerConsumer$Producer.run(ProducerConsumer.java:19)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
        at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
        at ProducerConsumer$Consumer.consume(ProducerConsumer.java:63)
        at ProducerConsumer$Consumer.run(ProducerConsumer.java:50)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This results from the fact that the call to the `notify();` method is not obeying to the its [contract:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify())

> **Wakes up a single thread that is waiting on this object's monitor.**
> (...)
> **This method should only be called by a thread that is the owner of
> this object's monitor.**

and the same applies for the `wait` method:

> **This method should only be called by a thread that is the owner of this object's monitor.**

**TL:DR**

You are calling `wait` and `notify()` on the wrong *lock* (*i.e.,* the *implicit* lock of the instance *return* by `this`).

Change, respectively, those calls to:

`lock.notify();` and `lock.wait();`

A running example based on the code provided:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class ProducerConsumer {
    final LinkedList<Integer> items =  new LinkedList<>();
    final Object lock = new Object();
    final int capacity = 10;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProducerConsumer m = new ProducerConsumer();
        Thread p = new Thread(m.new Producer());
        Thread c = new Thread(m.new Consumer());
        p.start();
        c.start();
    }

    class Producer implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                produce();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { /** do something **/ }
        }

        public void produce() throws InterruptedException {
            int value =0;
            while(true){
                synchronized (lock){
                    while(items.size() == capacity)
                        lock.wait();
                    items.add(++value);
                    System.out.println("Item Produced by "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Item "+value);
                    lock.notify();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Consumer implements Runnable{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                consume();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { /** do something **/ }
        }
        public void consume() throws InterruptedException {
            while (true){
                synchronized (lock){
                    while (items.size() == 0)
                            lock.wait();
                    System.out.println( "Item Consumed by "
                                        +Thread.currentThread().getName()+
                                        " Item "+items.remove());
                    lock.notify();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```